# Implement commutativity and associativity for custom operation

Tags: physics, algebra

Just to give context: I want to implement quantum mechanical ladder operators and for this I want Mathematica to realize when it can just commute my ladder operators with numbers or variables because they only act on Kets and Bras. So what I'm trying to implement is something like this: Mathematica should realize that

```
Times[CenterDot[ladder_op,variable],Ket[__Integer]]
```

is the same as

```
Times[variable,CenterDot[ladder_op,Ket[__Integer]]]
```

where `CenterDot` defines the operation of ladder operators on Kets. Basically, I want to be able to write

> ladder_op [CenterDot] variable [Times] Ket[__Integer]

or even

> ladder_op [Times] variable [CenterDot] Ket[__Integer]

The only way I could think of was to do this:

```
CenterDot[ladder_op_, HoldPattern[Times[variable__, Ket[y__]]]] /
:= Times[variable, CenterDot[ladder_op, Ket[y]]]
```

but then I need to write the above expression with parenthesis

> ladder_op [CenterDot] ( variable [Times] Ket[__Integer] )

and I would like to be able to neglect these parenthesis. So basically I just want to get as close as possible to how I would write this down on paper. Can anybody help?

Comment: This is neither commutativity nor associativity.

Comment: You are right, what would you call it?

Comment: This seems to a rehash of [this closed question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/168085). Why should we not close this one, too?

Comment: You might find useful information in this [documentation article](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/AssociatingDefinitionsWithDifferentSymbols.html)

Comment: Its a different problem I encountered. Its not a rehash.